# How to initialize Variables from Database and use them Globally in ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an API with NodeJs (expressJs).

I would be accessing 3rd party Services at several points using **API Keys** stored in my database(MySQL).

I was wondering if there was a way to initialize all the required API Keys from the database and save them as variables in a .Js file as soon as the server starts. Then require these files wherever the variables are needed.

I do not want to store the API KEYS plainly in any .js or .env file, but I want them to be found only in database, initialized at start of the program and then available everywhere.

Comment: It's unclear why you're trying to avoid putting them in a `.js` or `.env` file when your question asks how to save them to a `.js` file.   What is the difference?  And, why?

Comment: You can make a module which reads something from the database, stores it in a variable and then exports a function for retrieving that value.  Anyone can then import that module and call the function in it to get the saved value.

Comment: Thanks. I would be storing only references to the values in .js files. So when I wish to change the API Keys, I can change them only in the database and have the change reflect globally. Is there a better and safer way of achieving same? I'd be glad to get suggestions